# Android browser's drag event target not updating

Tags: android, sencha-touch, dom-events

When I attach a handler to the drag event (I'm using Sencha Touch) on Android,
the event's target does not reflect the current element I'm pointing above,
For example, if my drag started on element1 and during the drag, I moved to element2,
the event does not reflect this change.
While desktop browsers do reflect it (Chrome, Safari)...

I tried probing these attributes of the event (ev):
ev.event.target.id
ev.targetTouches[0].target.id
ev.target.id
ev.touches[0].target.id
ev.browserEvent.target.id
ev.gesture.target.id

All of which work perfectly fine on the desktop...

Any idea how can I extract the identity of the element I'm currently dragging above?

Thanks!